# Not able to run NETSH as admin

Tags: windows-7, netsh

I am unable to run the following command

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="testwifi" key=12345678
```

i get the following error
You must run this command from a command prompt with administrator privilege.

I am running cmd as administrator.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are right-clicking the command prompt icon and choosing to run it as an administrator?  If that is the case, please at the very least provide your Windows version.

Comment: yes i am running command prompt by right clicking  and run as administrator, I am running it on windows 7

Comment: Why are you not even confirming that you chose to run it as an administrator?  Did you?

Comment: yes i am running command prompt by right clicking  and run as administrator, I am running it on windows 7

Comment: Can you run `net session` in the command shell?  If you get `Access Denied` we know the shell itself is the problem, rather than `netsh`

Comment: yes I am able to run net session in cmd